# Testing a modal dialog with RSpec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I click 'Log In' on the navbar a modal dialog pops up rendering the log in partial.

How would I go about testing this using RSpec and Capybara?

```
<!--....-->
<li><%= link_to "Log in", '#', data: {:'reveal-id' => 'loginModal'} %></li>
<!--....-->

<div id="loginModal" class="reveal-modal">
  <%= render 'devise/sessions/new' %>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Althaf - can you confirm if the solution below worked for you?

Comment: Yes it did work as expected

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
visit your_page_path
click_link "Log in"
page.should have_content('a_modal_content_here') # async
```

Please consider using the following,

```
within('#loginModal') do
  page.should have_content('a_modal_content_here') # async
end
```

to look for your content in the modal only.

Comment: I thought this might be the way, but I'd have to ensure that the 'a_modal_content_here' is something unique to the modal right?

Comment: Well not necessary, you can use `within('#loginModal') { ... }` to look only in your modal html.

Comment: Great that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!